# Can I change AWSServiceConfiguration Region property for different buckets

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS, I am listing objects in a bucket; however, some buckets in the Amazon account have different regions. I can find these regions using:

```
[s3 getBucketLocation:locationRequest];
```

I want to be able to modify my existing `AWSServiceConfiguration` object with a new region to get the bucket data otherwise I get an endpoint exception. I am not sure if I can do this. Is there any other way or will I need a new configuration for every potential Region as this seems wrong to me somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should not manipulate `AWSServiceConfiguration` once it is set to a service client. You should have a separate client with a dedicated configuration per region.